# Why this php code only works for one user?

Tags: php

I have a login system in php. In my database I have only two people registred and the login system only works with the first one. 
I have alredy check the form but it doesn't work. Thank you

```
     <?php

    try{

        $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=pruebas_login" , 'root', '' );
        $conexion->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
        $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM USUARIOS_PASS WHERE USUARIOS= :login AND PASSWORD= :password"  ;
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($sql);
        $usuario = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['username'])); 
        $password = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['password']));

        $resultado->bindValue(":login", $usuario);//bindValue = bind_param solo que con marcadores
        $resultado->bindValue(":password", $password);
        $resultado->execute();

        $numero_registro = $resultado->rowCount();

        if($numero_registro != 0){

            session_start();
            $_SESSION["usuario"]=$_POST['username'];

            header("location:usuarios_registrados.php");

        }else{


                header("location:login.php");



        }



    }catch(Exception $e){

        die("Error". $e->getMessage());
    }


?>
```

Comment: Find out how many rows your rowcount gives you

Comment: 0 but I don't now why

Comment: And when i put the user that works 1, thank you for answer

Comment: vardump $_post to see the content

Comment: You don't need to escape your usernames and passwords if you're using prepared statements. Furthermore, **do not store passwords in plain text**. [Use PHP's `password_*` functions instead.](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

Comment: array(2) { ["username"]=> string(6) "user" ["password"]=> string(5) "password" }

Comment: I'm in a local page I'm learning php, so I don't wan't to encrypt the passwords. But thank you Bytewave

Comment: But it steal not working, but thank you a lot for this "escape your usernames and passwords if you're using prepared statements"

Comment: It's a good idea to learn that habit anyway. It's a trivial task, and the one time you forget or feel too lazy could be the app that gets breached and has everyone's passwords leaked. Get into the habit now, even on local non-public pages, so you're prepared for the future.

Comment: I take your advice, I will encrypt the passwords, but this bug is so frustrating. Thank you a lot sir.

Comment: If you're just lerning PHP, then don't don't on't use `htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['username']));` when you're  binding to the database query.... especially not ever with the password.... it actually weakens passwords

Comment: I have corrected that yet. But thank you a lot.

Comment: Unfortunatelly the bug steal there

Comment: You don't have any reason to [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) or to [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php). As the name and description of the latter says, it encodes the string as HTML. Use it when you generate HTML, not when you work with the database. And btw, the prepared statements were introduced to suppress the need to properly encode the values when the SQL is generated.

Answer (score 1):

The code should look like this this after $resultado->execute(). But make it fit with your style. I just add a fetch and save it as $data then use it as auth.

```
$data = $resultado->fetch();
if ($resultado->rowCount > 0)
{
    if (password_verify($password, $data['password']))
    {
        $_SESSION['user_session'] = $data['username'];
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I wil try that : )